# Java Regex - alphanumeric, allowing leading whitespace but not blank string

Tags: java, regex, string

I've been trying to make a java regex that allows only alphanumeric characters, which can have white spaces, BUT the whole string cannot be blank...

Few examples..

```
" hello world123" //fine
"hello123world" //fine
"hello123world " //fine
"    " //not allowed
```

So far I've gotten
    **^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$**
though this does not allow any leading whitespace and so any string with x number leading whitespace is not being matched.

Any ideas what I could add to the expression to allow leading whitespace?

Comment: How about `^[\s]*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$`? It's a bit over the top, but it will guarantee that there is a character somewhere in the middle and allow for some whitespace or no whitespace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about just `^\s*[\da-zA-Z][\da-zA-Z\s]*$`. 0 or more spaces at start, follow by at least 1 digit or letter followed by digits/letters/spaces.

Note: I did not use \w because \w includes "_", which is not alphanumeric.

Edit: Just tested all your cases on regexpal, and all worked as expected. This regex seems like the simplest one.

Comment: Nice, but I believe that you don't want to use `.*` since it will accept any characters (also including special characters like coma) but `[\d\w\s]*`

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, I suppose you are correct. The main point is that by this point you have done all the hard work so you dont care what comes next.

Comment: `\d` is redundant in `[\d\w]`, because `\w` *includes* `\d`: `\w == [\da-zA-Z_]`

Comment: @ah, you are correct. So actually I should keep the \d but replace the \w with a-zA-Z because I dont want the _.

Comment: also replace `[\da-zA-Z]+` with `[\da-zA-Z]` no need of + as it is covered by next *

Answer (score 3):

Just use a look ahead to assert that there's at least one non-blank:

```
(?=.*[^ ])[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+
```

This may be used as-is with `String.matches()`:

```
if (input.matches("(?=.*[^ ])[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")) {
    // input is OK
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test it using [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism `^(?=\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$`

`^(?=\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9])` will make regex to check if at start of the string it contains zero of more spaces `\\s*` and then character from class `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Demo:

```
String[] data = { 
        " hello world123", //fine
        "hello123world", //fine
        "hello123world ", //fine
        "    " //not allowed
         };

for(String s:data){
    System.out.println(s.matches("(?=.*\\S)[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*"));
}
```

output

```
true
true
true
false
```

Comment: I think the look up complicates things unnecessarily  and also reduced efficiency (though not much in this case).

Comment: @Dgrin91 you are right, but I will leave this answer as it is to show other ways of solving such problem. Maybe someone will have to use this form later :)